# Display dynamic data in scrollable tableview in Cocos2d

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, cocos2d-iphone

I am making an app in cocos2d. I am using SWTableView library for displaying dynamic contents in tableview in cocos2d. There is absolutely no problem when I am running sample code from [SWTableView Example](https://github.com/scanf/UITableView-cocos2d-test)
But when I load my data from server which is dynamic the tableview crashes on scroll.
It allows me to scroll well in the static data just like in the example but I am not able to figure out error as it just gives me BAD_ACCESS.

Note: Possible reason i feel is dynamic data.
      If any better method is there to load dynamic data in scrollable way in cocos2d then please suggest.

Thank u.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the solution. There was very strange problem but all working now.

Basically in the sample code (i mentioned in my question) there is a delegate method called

```
-(SWTableViewCell *)table:(SWTableView *)table cellAtIndex:(NSUInteger)idx;
```

here idx is NSUInteger but whenever i directly used it without converting it to int or NSInteger it gave BAD_ACCESS command.

Then i stored my data in MutableDictionary and gave it key as its index string 
i.e for name data of first person i gave key as "0" (string) and value as name.

Hence whenever i retrieved those values i used

```
[name objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", idx]]
```

which worked absolutely fine.

Also to mention here the other delegate called

```
-(NSUInteger)numberOfCellsInTableView:(SWTableView *)table;
```

returns an integer value, but when i used [Values count] my app used to crash on scroll.

Values is my main array where i store my data received from server.
Finally i started storing my data count in NSUserdefaults and my problem got solved.

Hope this helps somebody.